# How do I fix NU1701?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, elmah

Warning NU1701  Package 'elmah.corelibrary 1.2.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: This is library written for .NET Framewrok. You need to substitute it with analog for .NET Core.

Comment: Best to compile with latest version of Net and then target your CORE version.  Looks like that is what happened and nothing may be wrong.  You original code was compiled on a version of Net previous to 4.6.1.  Then was upgraded to Net 4.8 and was targeted to Core (Net 6.0).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jdweng how do I compile with the latest version of Net?

Comment: Download latest Net Version.  Then do clean build.  Check Project Target property and set to Latest Net Version.  Then do clean build.